# xcode 8.3 playground crashes

Tags: xcode

After a syntax error in a playground file, all my playgrounds display

"Encountered invalid state (5) upon execution".

[image]

I use XCode 8.3 (8E162) and Sierra 10.12.4
I restarted several times XCode, I also rebooted the computer.
I deleted derived data with
`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

What else should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried to update to Xcode 8.3.1?

Comment: Did you got a solution? This problem only appears in my user profile. If I switch to different user playground works fine. I have no idea what should I do, because i cleared all temp data related to Xcode (even simulators, derived data & config plist files).

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, and my computer's language is chinese instead of English.
Then I changed my initial language to english and the playground start to work.

You might want to check that.

Answer (score 0):

I too am having a similar problem. However when it occurred my MacBook freaked out and crashed. Reported the bug to apple. I uninstalled Xcode and installed it again that fixed the issue for me. Hope this get fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have also the same problem in my Mac Os Seirra.

#### Short answer:

I just Update my Mac Os Seirra, and This time the playground works Fine now!..